# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: node.ownerDocument is null

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to understand the reason for this failure and what I should modify in my script to work around this problem and be able to deliver the desired scraping. Follow the data:

Test site:

http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betlive/24

I'm trying to collect the links in these boxes:

[image]

The `find_element_by_xpath` is correct, but when I try to run the script, it returns the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: node.ownerDocument is null
```

My Script Project in Virtual Studio Code:

```
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import json

url = "http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betlive/24"

option = Options()
option.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=option)

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(1)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='rowLive']//a/@href")
html_content = element.get_attribute('outerHTML')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find(name='href')

df_full = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

importar = {}
importar['importando'] = df_full.to_dict('records')

print(importar['importando'])

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Is the element within a frame?  I am not able to access the link given- gives 403 error.

Comment: at which line is the error reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your bug here is that you are using `find_element_by_xpath` instead of `find_elements_by_xpath` in `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='rowLive']//a/@href")` line so this actually returns a single element while you attended to get all the links there.
So currently `html_content` is a HTML of a single element.
The same about the `soup` and `table` containers.

Comment: And the reason it's an error is that zeroth element is <a id="ip_21123943_start" class="Score">
    Ao Vivo
   </a> which has no href. So find_elements won't quite do it with that xpath. I think one needs get the ones with hrefs first or lose the @href and use get_attribute